# Oracle Check Constraint violation

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a constraint on the date column of the table `X`. When I created a check constraint on date as `date > '01-jan-2000'` there is an error message ("*Check constraint violated*"). When I tried again to check the date if it comes after 1996 (`date > '01-jan-1996'`), it worked well.

Is there a reason for it?

I used this code:

```
ALTER TABLE X 
ADD CONSTRAINT DATE_CONST CHECK(DATE>'01-JAN-2000')     --  ERROR

ALTER TABLE X 
ADD CONSTRAINT DATE_CONST CHECK(DATE>'01-JAN-1996')     --  WORKED
```

Comment: I don't think Oracle casts strings to dates.  You have to use `TO_DATE` or some such.

Comment: What is the actual type of this column? Is it a proper `DATE` or is it just a string?

Comment: @ nulluserexception  date type

Comment: The obvious question is, do you currently have any dates that would violate the first check, but not the second? (ie: what does `SELECT COUNT(*) from x WHERE date between '01-JAN-1996' and '01-JAN-2000'` give you?

Comment: @NullUserException: its giving me a value 3

Comment: That means you have rows which violate the first constraint, but not the second. That's why this is happening. You'll either have to fix those rows or change the constraint.

Comment: I just checked again, i was not able to create a constraint greater than 1998

Comment: @benny This means you have dates there that are smaller than 1998. You'll have to fix those rows if you want to create that constraint.

Answer (score 0):

there are two things you are done wrong.
a) You can not assing name to column keyword like "DATE".
b) you must to convert date when you add CONSTRAINT like this :

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT DATE_CONST CHECK(testdate>to_date('01-JAN-2000', 'dd-mon-yyyy'));
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98198/9 is example of this question.

Edit : If your table has record before specified date, Check constraint will be compiled but it will be invalid. You must be update before specied date records to newly date.

Comment: It's better to use a date value that is not dependent on the nls settings. `to_char('2000-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` or an ANSI Date literal `date '2000-01-01'` is much better

Comment: `'01-JAN-2000', 'dd-mon-yyyy'` still depends on the NLS *language*.